# I have a question involving logical quantifiers which I have been stuck on for a while. I have trouble understanding the concept.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

There is a question that has been bothering me where the concept is confusing to me. Assume B is the set of all boys and G is the set of all girls. L(B,G) represents that B likes G.

$$\forall b \in B, \forall g \in G, \neg L(b,g) \rightarrow \exists! h \in G [L(b,h) \wedge \forall c \in B \neg(L(c,g) \wedge L(c,h))] $$

From this statement, wont it be that the predicate contradicts with the existential? I know that statement is true, because the prof said so. So the predicate is true and none of the boys like none of the girls. So how can their exist a h that is a girl that likes a boy? I'm confused on this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is presumably meant to be interpreted with parentheses around everything after the first two quantifiers, like this: $$\forall b \in B, \forall g \in G, (\neg L(b,g) \rightarrow \exists! h \in G [L(b,h) \wedge \forall c \in B \neg(L(c,g) \wedge L(c,h))]).$$
So it's not asserting that if every boy dislikes every girl, then there exists a unique girl $h$ such that...  It's asserting that for each particular boy $b$ and each particular girl $g$, **if** $b$ dislikes $g$ **then** there exists a unique girl $h$ such that...

Note that with your interpretation, it doesn't even make sense to ask whether the statement is true: the variables $b$ and $g$ would be free in the second half of the statement, so the truth of the statement would depend on what values you plugged in for them.

Comment: Ohhhhh okkayy. Thanks I appreciate it a lot. Imma give it another look. Its part of a problem set I have to do and I just needed a push in the right direction bceuase I have been stuck on it a while. Thanks.